# Saving photo in my application

Tags: java, android, bitmap, uri, photo

I'm trying to save a photo that I have already captured in my application (to use it later like as an icon for my contact) but I don't know if I must change it from uri to bitmap or any other type.  I would like to save it as a .png like my others photos

```
Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, 1020);

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1020 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mImageUri = data.getData();
            Uri mImageUri2 = mImageUri;

            Uri aux1=mImageUri;
           Bitmap foto = photoUtils.getImage(aux1);
           Drawable fotofinal =new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),foto);
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: do you want to convert it into PNG?

Comment: yes, the photo i selected with galleryIntent save it in my aplication folder with the extension .png

Comment: Your code segment is missing some brackets.  This makes it difficult to clearly see what you're intending to do.